# Scala - Android App build fails

Tags: android, scala, ant

I am following the instructions to build Scala app for Android at:
[scala-to-android](http://lamp.epfl.ch/~michelou/android/scala-to-android.html)

Basically, I installed Scala and changed the ant build.properties to point to Scala and changed build.xml to include build-scala.xml.

```
ant scala-compile
```

is successful, However,

```
ant debug
```

generates the following build errors:

scala-compile:

```
-shrink-if-test:
     [echo] Checking if Scala libraries are installed on emulator or device...
      [adb] BOOTCLASSPATH=/system/framework/core.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/framework.jar:/system/framework/android.policy.jar:/system/framework/services.jar

-shrink-config:
  [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource scala/tools/ant/task.properties. It could not be found.

BUILD FAILED
/home/salil/Programs/android-projects/FirstScala/build-scala.xml:82: Problem: failed to create task or type invoked
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

I am a beginner in ant, Android and Scala. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced the same issue with android dev on Scala. Actually the build script looks for a file named task.properties which is located in scala/tools/ant/task.properties. This is packed inside the jar ant-invoked.jar. I hope you would have downloaded the android-sdk project zip archive from that site. Just copy the folder "configs" from the android-sdk root into your project root folder, this will work.
This is were it searches for the file in scala-build.xml

```
<!-- Project settings -->
property name="configs.dir" value="${basedir}/configs" />
<property name="ant-invoked.jar" value="${configs.dir}/ant/ant-invoked.jar" />
```

and the target shrink-config

```
<target name="-shrink-config"
        description="Generate ProGuard configuration file">
    <taskdef resource="scala/tools/ant/task.properties"
             classpath="${ant-invoked.jar}" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I copied the configs folder and fixed some paths in the build-scala.xml. However, it cannot find my main class file and ends up copying zero files to the output file. Here is the log:

Comment: scala-shrink:
ProGuard, version 4.4
Reading program directory [/home/salil/Programs/android-projects/FirstScala/bin/classes]
Reading program jar [/opt/scala-2.8.1.final/lib/scala-library.jar] (filtered)
Reading library jar [/opt/android-sdk-linux_86/platforms/android-7/android.jar]
Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'apt.scala'
Note: there were 1 references to unknown classes.
      You should check your configuration for typos.
Note: You're ignoring all warnings!

BUILD FAILED
build-scala.xml:158: The output jar is empty. Did you specify the proper '-keep' options?

Comment: OK, finally it all worked. It turned out that proguard config file generated in the bin folder does not specify the classname correctly. Instead of apt.scala.myscala class, it specifies apt.scala (the package name). Thank you for your help!

Comment: Strangely, it all worked on Windows, but not on Linux. Another major problem with this ant script is: the build-scala.xml ant script is written for android versions that did not come with a default proguard support. The new android SDKs have the default proguard config file associated. This file needs to be modified to point to the default proguard config file instead of generating its own. Maybe I will get it working after learning ant.

Comment: I had this problem too. Raam's advice and your comments helped solve it.
Works and tested for Android 2.2 and 3.0 under Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the most stable way to use Scala with android is to use the [Simple Build Tool (SBT)](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/) and the [Android Plugin](https://github.com/jberkel/android-plugin)

It basically "just works", handling all the steps for you and shrinking with Proguard.

Comment: Hi kevin, yes, I had to struggle a bit with ant to get it working (along with some manual tweaking of the config files automatically generated for the proguard. I will try SBT and Android plugin solution. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Kelvin, I tried sbt and android plugin. But, I am not happy with the android plugin. A few problems I noticed: a) It downloads a lot of scala packages (including the scala library) in the local library dependency folder instead of the shared folder. It does not bother to see whether I have these packages somewhere else. And I don't want to download these packages for every android project. b) Android plugin assumes that adb is in {android sdk}/tools folder instead of {android sdk}/platform-tools folder. And the build fails.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I have a blog here that documents steps to make scala work on android. It makes use of android ant process and sticks close to the android way. You can see the tutorial here
http://saadstechblog.blogspot.com/2011/09/scandroid-scala-android-tutorial.html.  There is also a github project with all the configuration.